# Upcast unique_ptr with template

Tags: c++, templates, unique-ptr

Consider the following simple code:

```
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    virtual T & foo() = 0;
};

struct Bar : public Foo<int>
{
    int x;
    virtual int & foo() override
    {
        return x;
    }
};

void baz(std::unique_ptr<Foo<int>>)
{
}

int main()
{
    auto up = std::make_unique<Bar>();
    baz(up);
    return 0;
}
```

It won't compile reporting this error:

```
prog.cc:27:9: error: could not convert 'up' from 'unique_ptr<Bar,default_delete<Bar>>' to 'unique_ptr<Foo<int>,default_delete<Foo<int>>>'
   27 |     baz(up);
      |         ^~
      |         |
      |         unique_ptr<Bar,default_delete<Bar>>
```

I wonder how I can solve this problem. [`share_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) seems to have proper casting methods to solve this *issue*, while it seems that for [`unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) there no alternatives.

Comment: `Foo` needs a `virtual` destructor

Comment: Your code wouldn't work as-is since a `std::unique_ptr` can't be copied. Scondly, why do you need to pass a `std::unique_ptr` here? Using raw pointers without ownership is not a bad thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are taking the argument in `baz` *by value*, which would imply *copying* a `std::unique_ptr` and... that's impossible (or `std::move`ing it, but I doubt that's what you want here).

Second of all, `std::unique_ptr` doesn't convert because that would require copying.

What's the workaround?

You can do:

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo<int>> up = std::make_unique<Bar>();
```

instead of:

```
auto up = std::make_unique<Bar>();
```

and take the argument in `baz` *by reference*:

```
void baz(std::unique_ptr<Foo<int>>&) { ... }
```

---

First thing is to save a `unique_ptr` to derived in a `unique_ptr` to base. `auto` cannot do that, unless you use a cast.

Second thing is, as aforementioned, to *not copy* the `unique_ptr`.

What's more, you code exhibits *undefined behaviour*, because you delete the derived class object with a base class pointer. That requires a `virtual` destructor in the base class.

Comment: Ops... Right, I just forgot to move! Shame on me! BTW using the reference approach means that I can pass the unique pointer without moving, but this could make not clear if the `baz` function will move internally, right? So in my case I would prefer to force a move.

Comment: passing by non-`const` reference does not imply that the object is read-only, so `std::move` will be valid, but you are right - taking it by value (or by rvalue reference), which would require a move would make a better implication that `baz` will move internally.

Comment: Are you sure you can pass `up` by reference?

Comment: @n.m Could you elaborate? Are you concerned about the actual use-case logic (which OP clarified in the comment above - he actually prefers move to pass by `&`) or about the syntactic correctness?